# MySQL: Get the records whose largest value in another field is below some threshold

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I've got 2 tables in MySQL, call them account and note:

```
Account
- Id
- Available (bool)

Note
- Id
- When (DateTime)
- AccountId (FKey)
```

I'd like to update the accounts whose *most recent* note is below some threshold (say 90 days ago). In SQL, I'd like something like the following (which obviously doesn't work due to the way max works)

```
UPDATE 
    Account INNER JOIN Note ON Account.Id = Note.AccountId
SET
    Account.Available = true
WHERE
    Max(Note.When) < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -90 DAY);
```

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Untested, but I think this would work.

```
UPDATE 
    Account
SET
    Account.Available = true
WHERE
    Id IN(
        SELECT 
            AccountId 
        FROM 
            Note 
        GROUP BY 
            AccountId 
        HAVING 
            Max(Note.When) < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -90 DAY)
    );
```

Comment: +1 I don't think you'd even need to perform the INNER JOIN in your version.

Comment: You are correct, the INNER JOIN is not needed. Copy / paste strikes again :)

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't use aggregate functions in the where clause (Max(Note.When))

Comment: +1: I had just figured out the having clause and came to update this when I saw your post. Thank you retailevolved.